# Localhost networking in Docker with compose

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a docker-compose project that has a Nextjs service, Node API service, and Nginx. I'm running this on my local machine.
The problem is:
I can reach the frontend (nextjs) vis Nginx localhost:80 forwarded to port 3000. I can also reach the graphql API (via Nginx localhost:4000

But when I try to use `nextauth` it tries to connect to localhost:4000..then gets a `connection refused`. I think the problem is that it tries to access localhost:4000 in the container, so it's trying to access itself, but in reality, it needs to access the API. Regular API calls work when coming from the browser.

I have also tried `network_mode:host` but with no luck.

Here is my current docker compose file:

```html
version: "3"
services:
  nexusdb:
    network_mode: "host"
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      # POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Ck6029iwa
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: Ck6029iwa
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: nexus
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-p", "5432", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 45s
      interval: 10s
      retries: 20
  nextjs:
    network_mode: "host"
    build: ./
  nginxfrontend:
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  nginxapi:
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    build: ../nexus-api/nginx
    ports:
      - 4000:4000

  nexusapi:
    build: ../nexus-api
    network_mode: "host"
    depends_on:
      nexusdb:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: I have tried network_mode:host with no luck

Comment: use `docker.internal.host` instead of `localhost`, you can also use the service names from the compose file as DNS records for the applications running under them